# Extract to method with empty returns

Tags: php, refactoring

So I have a method to update a customer status. This method is also doing some validations along the way, and I think the validations should be separated and `updateCustomerStatus` method should only update (for single responsibility purposes).

If either `firstCondition` or `secondCondition` holds, then I'll do nothing. Otherwise the status will be updated, and this will run for a list of customer id's. Also, I've kept the conditions separated because the messages are specific for each condition.

So I have something like the following:

```
private function updateCustomerStatus($customerId) {
    $customer = findCustomerById($customerId); 
    
    [...]

    if (firstCondition($customer)) {
        echo "first condition text"; // not actually a echo, so I can't simply return the text
        return ;  
    }

    if (secondCondition($customer)) {
        echo "second condition text";  // same as above 
        return ;  
    }

    updateCustomer($customerId); 
}
```

How could I extract the conditions onto a method?

I've tried to refactor it, but since I have the empty returns (`return ;`) I can't seem to figure it out, and also I can't remove them since a specific message should be displayed when a specific condition holds and it's not actually an echo, it's another void method used to display messages.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're wanting to do.  Can't you just return the condition text?  And return updateCustomer(), which could just simply be an empty string.

Comment: My bad! It's not actually an echo, it is another void method used to display messages, and therefore I cannot return it.

Comment: Unable to get your requirement.... come with working code... then only we help you

Answer (score 0):

How I would do it:

```
interface CustomerValidationInterface
{
    public function isValid(Customer $customer): bool;
}

class CustomerFooValidator implements CustomerValidationInterface
{
    public function isValid(Customer $customer)
    {
        return $customer->foo === 'FOO';
    }
}

class CustomerBarValidator implements CustomerValidationInterface
{
    public function isValid(Customer $customer)
    {
        return $customer->bar === 'BAR';
    }
}

class CustomerValidator
{
    private $validators;

    /**
     * @param CustomerValidationInterface[] $validators
     */
    public function __construct(array $validators)
    {
        $this->validators = $validators;
    }

    public function check(Customer $customer)
    {
        foreach ($this->validators as $validator) {
            if ($validator->isValid($customer) === false) {
                return 'error';
            }
        }

        return 'success'
    }
}
```

you can future proof your code, if you need more things to validate in the future, you just need to create a new class implementing your interface and pass to the main validator class.

Update customer status IMHO should do what it says, update the customer status, not check for validation. You should do validation 1 step before this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to refactor your code so that the *updateCustomerStatus()* method only contains **business logic**, i.e. checking the invariants on the customer before allowing to update it.

Currently you would call **UI logic** inside this method (even if the echo is happening in a separate method). I'd like to move the actual rendering of the UI out of updateCustomerStatus().

And I will even go a step further an also move the **database access** portion (findCustomerById()) out of the business logic method.

This way you can also test the business logic in isolation without needing to worry about the UI and the database.

So here is the direction in which I would move when refactoring your code:

So let's start top-down with some fictional public method that orchestrates the steps and calls your private methods:

```
public function doUpdateCustomerStatusStuff(string $customerId): void
{
    $customer = $this->findCustomerById($customerId);
    $operationResult = $this->updateCustomerStatus($customer);

    if ($operationResult->failed()) {
        $this->showMessage($operationResult->getMessage());
    }
}
```

As you can see it first fetches the customer from the database so that your business logic can now operate on a customer object without having database dependencies.

In the next step we look into the refactored updateCustomerStatus() method:

```
private function updateCustomerStatus(Customer $customer): OperationResult
{
    if ($this->firstCondition($customer)) {
        return OperationResult::fail('first condition text');
    }

    if ($this->secondCondition($customer)) {
        return OperationResult::fail('second condition text');
    }

    $this->updateCustomer($customer);

    return OperationResult::succeed();
}
```

I now pass in the Customer object rather than the id so that the logic code can already do it's job.

Now to **your original question**:

Instead of calling the UI method (with the echo statement) I rather return some Result object that indicates if the operation succeeded or failed and which also provides an optional message. I added some static methods to the OperationResult class just for convenience.

Let's look at the class, it is not complex but does it's job:

```
class OperationResult
{
    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    private $success;
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $message;

    private function __construct(bool $success)
    {

        $this->success = $success;
    }

    private function setMessage(string $message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    public static function fail(string $message)
    {
        $result = new OperationResult(false);
        $result->setMessage($message);
    }

    public static function succeed()
    {
        return new OperationResult(true);
    }

    public function failed()
    {
        return !$this->success;
    }

    public function succeeded()
    {
        return $this->success;
    }
}
```

Now back to the fictional *doUpdateCustomerStatusStuff()* method:

```
public function doUpdateCustomerStatusStuff(string $customerId): void
{
    $customer = $this->findCustomerById($customerId);
    $operationResult = $this->updateCustomerStatus($customer);

    if ($operationResult->failed()) {
        $this->showMessage($operationResult->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Now you can control when and how to output a message (if any) **AFTER** the business logic with all checking and updating rules has been performed.

You can even go a step further and move all business logic methods (such as updateCustomerStatus() into a separate class which only contains business logic).

*Note*: I just assumed that *firstCondition()* and *secondCondition()* would check for error conditions. But if that is not the case you can of course perform the output of the message also depending on if there is some message in the doUpdateCustomerStatusStuff() method.